# Uploading image failing on php back-end

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to implement a small update profile pic form.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $filename;?>" name="change_picture_form" id="change_picture_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_picture" />
    <input type="file" name="new_user_picture">
    <input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

The target php file has the following code:

```
echo $_FILES['new_user_picture']['size']." ";
echo $_FILES['new_user_picture']['tmp_name']." ";
echo $_FILES['new_user_picture']['name']." ";
echo $_FILES['new_user_picture']['error']." ";
echo $_FILES['new_user_picture']['type']." ";
$picture_uploaded = $_FILES["new_user_picture"]["tmp_name"];
if( is_uploaded_file( $picture_uploaded ) ) {
    $imagesize = getimagesize( $picture_uploaded );
    switch( $imagesize[2] ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
              $extension = '.png';
              echo "<script>console.log('Reached here!!')</script>";
              try {
                  $image_original = imagecreatefrompng( $picture_uploaded );
                  if (!$image_original)
                      echo '<script>console.log("not image original")</script>';
              } catch(Exception $e) {
                  echo "<script>console.log('Error!!')</script>";
              }
              break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: ....
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, I have similar code for many image types. I tested this code by trying to uploading a png image. The first 5 echo statements display expected results - the size, error value of zero, the name, the type and the temp name.

I get "Reached here!!" on my console.
`imagecreatefrompng`, however, seems to crash silently. Try-catch somehow doesn't seem to catch the error.

Help? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean 'crash silently' you get any error in log or screen?

Comment: I guess you cannot do directly conversion to temporary uploaded files, how about you do move_uploaded_file() then perform the imagecreatefrom png ?

Comment: @Navneet the code works as written . I don't see anything wrong in it . You will be getting a resource id for `imagecreatefrompng()` function, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php , ie why you are not getting not image original.

Comment: I have tried moving first. Initially, I thought the problem was with permissions. But it still is there. So, now I copy the file to another folder and then, call imagecreatefrompng(). I get no error on the console at all. I put in some echo statements after this function call and none of them appear on the page or the console.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't handled file uploads in PHP in forever, but is it possible that this line:

```
$picture_uploaded = $_FILES["new_user_picture"]["tmp_name"]
```

should be

`$picture_uploaded = $_FILES["new_user_picture"]` ?

The first line, as is, should be getting you the uploaded file's file name, whereas the second line (the edited line above) should be a reference to the file itself.

HTH.

**EDIT:** Well, seeing as how my answer is incorrect... does this help?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php
. There's a helper function in the user notes/comments that might simplify what you're doing

Comment: The functions actually require filenames and paths. This would not work.

Comment: Sure enough. Just finished perusing the manual and was about to edit my answer accordingly... sorry. :p